# Best way of storing level and exp for text based game - Python 3.x

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I'm currently trying to write a text-based game, in python.

I want to use an experience based system within it

What is the best way to store the values

eg.

```
Level 1 = 100
Level 2 = 200
Level 3 = 500
Level 4 = 800
```

I don't know if to use a list or dictionary, and can you also please show some examples of how to do it.

Thanks!

eg:
Edit: 
I have tried this

```
levels = []
    #levels = {"Level":"0", "XPNeed":"0"}
    level = 1
    n = 1
    expneeded = 0
    expneeded = 100
    levels = {"Level":0, "XPNeed":0}
    print(levels)
    #print(levels)
    #print(len(levels))
    """print(levels.get("Level")[0])
    print(levels.get("XPNeed")[0])"""
    newXPNeed = levels["XPNeed"] + (level * 100)
    print(newXPNeed)
    #print(str(levels.get("XPNeed")[0] + (level * 100)))


    while len(levels) <= 31:
        newXPNeed = levels["XPNeed"][n] + (level * 100)
        experiencecalc = str(newXPNeed)
        print(experiencecalc)
        levelReq = {'Level':n, 'XPNeed':experiencecalc}
        print(levelReq)
        level += 1
        levels.append(levelReq)
        n += 1
```

Comment: Can you show any attempts you've made so far? Not sure what storing a property file has to do with Python

Comment: both can be used , but I suggest using dictionary, because later maybe you want to add some additional data to that.

Comment: Depends what you want. Effectiveness or ease of use? Maybe 2d array or pandas dataframe. I'm quite sure everyone have their own preferences.

Comment: You want to get this data every time when running the game? I would suggest to go with either JSON or YAML - place data there, then load it from file - that will give you much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comments that the easiest way to do this might be to have an external properties file that houses the leveling information. If you wanted to do this purely within the code itself, you could define a 'level object' to house the fields that matter for leveling, and then store a dictionary of level objects using the level number as the key:

```
class LevelObject(object):

    def __init__(self, level_number, minimum_exp_bound, maximum_exp_bound):
        self._level_number = level_number
        self._minimum_exp_bound = minimum_exp_bound
        self._maximum_exp_bound = maximum_exp_bound

    @property
    def level_number(self):
        return self._level_number

    @property
    def minimum_exp_bound(self):
        return self._minimum_exp_bound

    @property
    def maximum_exp_bound(self):
        return self._maximum_exp_bound


def main():
    level_dictionary = {}

    level_dictionary[0] = LevelObject(0, 0, 99)
    level_dictionary[1] = LevelObject(1, 100, 199)
    level_dictionary[2] = LevelObject(2, 200, 499)
    level_dictionary[3] = LevelObject(3, 500, 799)
    level_dictionary[4] = LevelObject(4, 800, 1499)
    # Etc...

    for key, value in level_dictionary.iteritems():
        print 'Level: %s  Min Exp: %s  Max Exp: %s' % (value.level_number, value.minimum_exp_bound, value.maximum_exp_bound)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

>>>Level: 0  Min Exp: 0  Max Exp: 99
>>>Level: 1  Min Exp: 100  Max Exp: 199
>>>Level: 2  Min Exp: 200  Max Exp: 499
>>>Level: 3  Min Exp: 500  Max Exp: 799
>>>Level: 4  Min Exp: 800  Max Exp: 1499
```

What I've included above is just a mock-up of what the object/dictionary could look like, along with a print statement so that you can validate what the output from the dictionary would return. Within your code, you would likely want to store the object code in its own file, and import it into the main portion of your code.